# The best way to pull a list of all apps from Azure AD with "Users or groups" they may have

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, saas

The task is to pull a list of all Enterprise Apps from Azure AD and list how they are levered either with assigned groups or direct users, Going through each app is time-consuming. I tried some PS, but the best was I pulled a list of apps with some attributes that I don't need.  Any help is appreciated.
thank you

Comment: You could use `Microsoft Graph API` to pull those information.  For example `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserId/memberOf`. More details can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/group?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: For Application you can try this `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications`

Comment: Any input on how to use graph API ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below PowerShell Script to get the expected output as you are looking for.

```
# Get all service principals, and for each one, get all the app role assignments, 
# resolving the app role ID to it's display name. Output everything to a CSV.
Get-AzureADServicePrincipal | % {  
  # Get the app role assignments for this app, and add a field for the app role name
  Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId ($_.ObjectId)
} | Export-Csv "app_role_assignments.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

[image]

**Output-- Enterprise Application and their corresponing Users and Groups name.**

[image]

Example : From Portal from one Enterprise App ie `AWS Single-Account Access`

[image]

Refernce : https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/48159

Comment: This works nicely to an extend. First of all, - huge thanks because at least I get what I need, the only problem is for whatever reason it only populates a few apps, in fact, we have hundreds of them. Any input is aprpeciated

Comment: It is populating only those apps who's user and group assigned to them.

Comment: It will not populate those apps in which there is no user and gorups

Comment: YOu mentioned user and groups, so It must have either or? Is there a way to have all lists of apps and their corresponding assignments whether its a user or a group + if an app does not have anything, still show it

Comment: Sure. Will try to modify my PowerShell Command and will get back to you.

Comment: Thanks let me know if any luck, this becomes painful

Comment: @GlockAmole i tried but i am not getting expected output as you are looking. Because Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment is only gives the apps name who's assigment of user & Group. You can manualy filter it from as Get-AzureADServicePrincipal gives all apps name.

Comment: Even Tried to find logic behind of this AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment pwshell scirpt but not any luck.

Comment: – RahulKumarShaw-MT  Yeah, not getting results still. Are there any tools or add-ins that could do that?

Comment: @GlockAmole not sure. Will look it again and get back to you if i find something.